# Storing arrays in memory and using these arrays later

Tags: java

I am currently working on a program which requires preprocessing; filling multidimensional arrays with around 5765760*2 values.

My issue is that I have to run this preprocessing every time before I actually get to test the data and it takes around 2 minutes.

I don't want to have to wait 2 minutes each time I run a test, but I also don't want to store the values in a file.

Is there a way to store the values in a temporary memory rather than actually outputting them into a file?

Comment: Not if you don't keep the program (or another program) running, to keep the data in memory. What's wrong with files?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to store the values in a file? That seems the obvious way forward IMO.

Comment: I thought so too, but my advisor said  "the value's needn't be stored in a file, just create a data structure" @JonSkeet He also explained that reading and writing to a file is too costly, which I couldn't understand because these multidimensional arrays only needs to be created once

Comment: *"my advisor said "the value's needn't be stored in a file, just create a data structure He also explained that reading and writing to a file is too costly"* This highly depends on how that values are created currently. If the values are created by simple calculations on indexes reading them from a file may in deed be more expensive. However, why don't you change your code to be parameterizes and create only small arrays for testing?

Comment: I am creating sparse indexes for additive pattern database heuristics, creating small arrays isn't possible @TimothyTruckle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, what you are asking for translates to: "can I make my JVM write data to some place in memory so that **another** JVM instance can later on read from there?"

And the simple answer is: **no**, that is not possible.

When the JVM dies, the memory consumed by the JVM is returned to the OS. That stuff is **gone**.

So even the infamous [sun.misc.Unsafe](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/direct-memory-access-in-java/) with "direct" memory access does not allow you to do that.

The one thing that would work: if your OS is Linux, you could create a [RAM disc](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux). And then you write your file to that.

So, yes, you store your data in a file, but the file resides in memory; thus reading/writing is much faster compared to disk IO. And that data stays available as long as you don't delete the RAM disc or restart your OS.

On the other hand, when your OS is Linux, and you have enough RAM (a few GB should do!) then you should just try if an "ordinary disc" isn't good enough.

You see - those modern OSes, they do a lot of things in the background. It might look like "writing to disk", but in the end, the Linux OS just keeps using the memory.

So, before you spent hours on bizarre solutions - measure the impact of writing to disk!

Comment: Thank you for that, I suppose the best method would be writing to a file!

Comment: ahh okay, I'll have a look into it. I mean the array sizes that I'm storing are of this nature `a[16][16][16][16][16][16]`

Comment: Unless each "value" represents a multi MB blob ... that is nothing. 16^6 ... thats like 16 MB (unless I am mistaken). That is **nothing** on any decent piece of modern hardware.

Comment: Final word: never forget about http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization ... like in: before spending hours how to not save data, measure how long writing / reading that file takes.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. Get to sleep! :D

Answer (score 0):

Run the preprocessing, save the result using a data structure of your choice and keep your programm running until you need the result.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be stored in memory?  Well, yes, it's already in memory!  The obvious solution is to keep your program running.  You can put your program in a loop with an option to repeat - "enter Y to test again, or N to quit."  Then, your program can skip the preprocessing if it's already been done.  Until you exit the program, you can do this as many times as you like.

Another thing you might consider is whether your code can be made more efficient.  If your code takes less time to run, it won't be quite so annoying to wait for it.  In general, if something can be done outside a loop, don't do it inside a loop.  If you have an instruction being run five million times, that can add up.  If this is homework, you'll likely use more time making it more efficient than you'd spend waiting for it - however, this isn't wasted time, as you're practicing skills you may need later.  Obviously, I can't give specific suggestions without the code (and making specific code more efficient would probably be better suited for the Code Review stack exchange site.)